# Elasticsearch - Getting multiple documents with multiple custom offset and size 1

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently, the way I use to get multiple documents with exact query but different positions offset with size 1 is to use Elastic Search Multi Search API. I wonder if there is any better way to do this that would result in a better performance.

The example of current query I am using  :

```
{"index" : "test"}
{"query" : {"term" : { "user" : "Kimchy" }}, "from" : a, "size" : 1}
{}
{"query" : {"term" : { "user" : "Kimchy" }}, "from" : b, "size" : 1}
{}
{"query" : {"term" : { "user" : "Kimchy" }}, "from" : c, "size" : 1}
{}
{"query" : {"term" : { "user" : "Kimchy" }}, "from" : d, "size" : 1}
{}
{"query" : {"term" : { "user" : "Kimchy" }}, "from" : e, "size" : 1}
....
```

where a,b,c,d,e is a parameter given when query.

Comment: I'm puzzled, why don't you issue a single query with `from: a` and `size: 5`?

Comment: @Val a,b,c,d,e is a random number, so using size query will end up like what **pythonHelpRequired** stated below.

Comment: You should really explain your concrete use case behind this need. There might be other ways. As it stands, the approach looks flawed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly a,b,c,d,e will all be numbers right?, so you basically want to be able to ask elastic search for say the 3rd, 4th, and 7th documents that show up in a specific query?

I'm not sure if it is the best way to do things, but it would certainly be faster to find the smallest and largest numbers in a through e then do "from : smallest" and "size : largest-smallest". Then take the results that ES returns and go through it yourself to get the specific documents.

Every time you do a from/size query elastic search has to find all the queries before that number anyways so you are currently basically redoing the same search over and over.

This approach does get sketchy if there is a large difference between your smallest and biggest numbers though, and you may end up trying to send back thousands of documents.

Comment: Yep, but the problem is like what you stated before, (largest - smallest) is big enough, so I guess it has network I/O problems.